# How to connect a client to an IRC server using sockets in C

Tags: c, sockets, winsock, irc

I am coding an IRC client that I want to connect to irc.hackerzvoice.net.
I have read [RFC1459](http://www.mirc.com/rfc1459.html) as well as similar posts here on Stackoverflow, but still do not get what can possibly be wrong in my code.
I still get the same "registration timeout" error after sending the NICK and USER messages.

```
La socket 280 est ouverte en TCP/IP.
Connexion a 212.83.153.145 sur le port 6667
68 octets ont ete recus
texte recu : :irc.hackerzvoice.net NOTICE Auth :*** Looking up your hostname...
16 octets envoyes au serveur
texte envoye : NICK parallel
.30 octets envoyes au serveur
texte envoye : USER parallel * * :parallel
.99 octets ont ete recus
texte recu : :irc.hackerzvoice.net NOTICE Auth :*** Found your hostname (catv-89-132-88-100.catv.broadband.hu)
92 octets ont ete recus
texte recu : ERROR :Closing link: (unknown@catv-89-132-88-100.catv.broadband.hu) [Registration timeout]
d.hu)
0 octets ont ete recus
texte recu : ERROR :Closing link: (unknown@catv-89-132-88-100.catv.broadband.hu) [Registration timeout]
d.hu)
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "root_me_1.h"
 
 
int main()
{
    // Si la plateforme est Windows
    #if defined (WIN32)
        WSADATA WSAData;
        WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &WSAData); // sert à initialiser la bibliothèque WinSock
    #endif
 
    // socket et interface de connexion
    SOCKET sock;
    SOCKADDR_IN sin; // structure
 
    char buffer[TAILLE_MAX] = "";
    int nOctetsRecus = 0;
    int nOctetsEnvoyes = 0;
    int tailleBuffer = 0;
    int boucle = 1;
 
    // on crée une socket utilisant protocole TCP/IP
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
        printf("Erreur, socket non valide");
    printf("La socket %d est ouverte en TCP/IP.\n", sock);
 
    // on configure l'interface de connexion
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("212.83.153.145"); // adresse IP du serveur IRC
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(PORT); // sin_port et sin_addr doivent être en Network Byte Order // htons() convertit un entier court depuis l'ordre des octets de l'hôte vers celuidu réseau (host to network short)
 
    if(connect(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&sin, sizeof(sin)) != SOCKET_ERROR) // si le client réussit à se connecter au serveur
        printf("Connexion a %s sur le port %d\n", inet_ntoa(sin.sin_addr), htons(sin.sin_port));
    else
        printf("Erreur de connexion.");
 
 
    // on reçoit les données envoyées par le serveur
    nOctetsRecus = recv(sock, buffer, TAILLE_MAX, 0);
    if(nOctetsRecus != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("%d octets ont ete recus\n", nOctetsRecus);
        printf("texte recu : %s", buffer);
    }
    else
        printf("Les donnees n'ont pas ete recues");
 
 
    // le client envoie des données au serveur
    sprintf(buffer, "NICK parallel\r\n");
    tailleBuffer = strlen(buffer)+1; // taille de la chaine + '\0'
 
    nOctetsEnvoyes = send(sock, buffer, tailleBuffer, 0);
    if(nOctetsEnvoyes != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("%d octets envoyes au serveur\n", nOctetsEnvoyes);
        printf("texte envoye : %s", buffer);
    }
    else
        printf("Erreur : donnees non envoyees au serveur");
 
    // le client envoie des données au serveur
    sprintf(buffer, "USER parallel * * :parallel\r\n");
    tailleBuffer = strlen(buffer)+1; // taille de la chaine + '\0'
 
    nOctetsEnvoyes = send(sock, buffer, tailleBuffer, 0);
    if(nOctetsEnvoyes != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("%d octets envoyes au serveur\n", nOctetsEnvoyes);
        printf("texte envoye : %s", buffer);
    }
    else
        printf("Erreur : donnees non envoyees au serveur");
 
 
    // on reçoit les données envoyées par le serveur
    nOctetsRecus = recv(sock, buffer, TAILLE_MAX, 0);
    if(nOctetsRecus != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("%d octets ont ete recus\n", nOctetsRecus);
        printf("texte recu : %s", buffer);
    }
    else
        printf("Les donnees n'ont pas ete recues");
 
 
    // on ferme la connexion
    closesocket(sock);
 
 
    #if defined (WIN32)
        WSACleanup(); // libère les ressources allouées par la fonction WSAStartup()
    #endif
 
    getchar();
 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Would you have an idea of the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Your error handling is wrong, you check for possible errors but still continue with the program.

Comment: Probably most of the people reading this do not speak/read french.

Comment: Also, 'printf("texte recu : %s", buffer);' will fail if TAILLE_MAX chars are read - the buffer is then not guaranteed NUL-terminated.  I suggest reading TAILLE_MAX-1 chars.

Comment: Note: I added the winsock tag,since you appear to use a windows socket implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem,

```
sprintf(buffer, "NICK hoeplem\r\n");
tailleBuffer = strlen(buffer)+1;
```

Because `strlen(buffer) + 1` is one byte off (*the `null` terminator `'\0'` should not be sent to the server and `strlen()` returns the **length** of the string excluding the `null` terminator.*) the actual length of the string. If the server reads that byte it might be expecting `'\r\n'` to flush the buffer and process the command, so it's waiting forever after the last "*command*".

It should be

```
tailleBuffer = sprintf(buffer, "NICK hoeplem\r\n");
```

and that way it would be perfect.

You might also want to check [POSIX's `dprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html) and/or roll your own `dprintf()` to avoid `sprintf()`ing every time.

Also, it would be better to have each command as a function with it's parameters and simply call `command_X(sock, PARAMETERS ...)` for every possible command, that way your code would be more robust.

Comment: Didn't DV, but also do not get your answer.

Comment: *If* the server's protocol is line-oriented, I'd send exactly the length of the string. I would not send the `0`-terminator. Is this what you want to express?

Comment: I understand you now. Still I'd mention explicitly which byte "*that byte*" is.

Comment: The '\0' posed problem indeed, now it works. Thanks!